# Why isn't gtag sending ad conversion tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I'm using `gtag`.js to track Google Ads.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-abc123"></script>

<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-abc123');
</script>
```

This is the code to trigger my Google Ads Conversion Tracking pixel:

```
var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-abc123/12345',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
```

When I load my page with a fresh cache, I can see my conversion pixel being fired:

[image]

However, after a page reload, the conversion no longer fires:
[image]

What is causing the conversion tag to stop firing?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that tag doesn't fire? Blue color in Tag Assistant indicates non-standard implementation etc. Try to click on your tag in Tag Assistant and see details.

Comment: In screenshot #1, the tag in question is marked as `Google Ads Conversion Tracking`. In #2 it is `Google Ads Remarkting Tag`. I would expect them both to be the same, that is why I don't think the tag is firing correctly.

Comment: Maybe this is due to the settings of conversion tag? Does it fire once per session or one per day for unique user?